# How to quickly resize an image

Tags: discussion

E.g. here: [Can Mathematica solve functional equations with nested variable?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114210/5478)

original pictures are way to big. Smaller pictures are improving readability, unless they are too small and you can't read the content.

Can I quickly add a html tag or whatever? I'd go with import->resize->upload but I'm to lazy today :)

Comment: I was wondering the same thing

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Imgur natively supports a handful of different sizes for the same image, which you can access by just changing the URL of the image (see the last letter of the URLs in 2-7 with respect the first one):

1. Original: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEZJ5.png
2. Huge: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEZJ5h.png
3. Large: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEZJ5l.png
4. Medium: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEZJ5m.png
5. Thumbnail: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEZJ5t.png
6. Big square: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEZJ5b.png
7. Small square: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEZJ5s.png

So what I typically do is to display the image as a medium sized one, but link it to the high-res one:

```
[![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEZJ5m.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEZJ5.png)
```

Comment: better than I was expecting, thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

The `img` tag works:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEZJ5.png" width="{integer}" >
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great observation! Don't know why I never tried that...

Comment: This works with gifs while the accepted answer isn't (just leaving static thumbnail).